# Semicolon in url - chrome vs IE & Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, download

Given a url, my application tries to download the file, e.g., `http://foo.com/bar.bat` will download bar.bat

Now, given a version number at the end delimited by semi-colon, my application will retrieve that particular version from my source control and download the file.

For e.g., `http://foo.com/bar.bat;1` should download bar.bat version 1. 
`http://foo.com/bar.bat;2` should download bar.bat version 2 etc.

Problem:
Chrome downloads the right version as bat file.
IE (am using IE 11) and firefox downloads the right version but considers 'bat;1' or 'bat;2' as the file type instead of 'bat'.

I have mime type as application/bat. I tried with '%3b' instead of ';' but same issue.

No idea what else to check.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you chose this approach over something more standard, such as a query string parameter?

Comment: I did not choose this. It is a legacy perl code which i did not develop and i dont know perl language. Thought i will check if there is any other way i can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use `http://foo.com/bar.bat?version=1` instead?  this should work on every browser properly because it is a standard.

Comment: The approach works fine for zip, zipx and every other extension except bat and msi. As i said above, the code is in perl. So i was wondering if there is anything special i can do to make it work for bat and msi.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by making a code change in Perl (with Google's assistance, of course).

In case, anyone intererested or face this problem in future, here is what i did.

In perl code, redirect to `http://foo.com/bar.bat;1` was happening with relative path.

```
print $query->redirect(-uri => $redirect); # $redirect being '/bar.bat;1'
```

I gave absolute path like below

```
    my $RemoteHost = $query->url(-base=>1); #this gets http://foo.com
    my $newredirect = "$RemoteHost$redirect";     
    print $query->redirect(-uri => $newredirect);
```

I will mark erikvold's as answer since he triggered me to look at the perl code.
Thanks Jonathan and erikvold.